# Reference EL function from xhtml located in same jar

Tags: maven, jsf, el, taglib

So, I have a jar that contains several common .xhtml files that I use in my web project (JSF2.2 in a Wildfly 8.1 server) as custom components.

Also, in the same .jar I have a utility class ( ViewUtils ) that has a function that I call from the .xhtml files located in my web project.

The thing is that I actually want to access that EL function from the .xhtml files located in the same jar where the function is, and I can't. JBoss says that the EL expression is not recognized. However, I am able to call that function from the .xhtml files located in my web project (.war)

Do I explain myself?
Here is the code.

This is the code in my .jar

```
public final class ViewUtils {

(...)

public static String getEnumMessageKey(final Enum<?> e) {

        String key = "";

        try {
            key = "enum_" + e.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + '_' + e.name().toLowerCase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.debug("Key not found or null.");
        }

        return key;
    }

(...)

}
```

custom.taglib.xml

```
<namespace>http://mycompany.com/taglib</namespace>
<composite-library-name>conexiacomponent</composite-library-name>

<function>
    <function-name>enum_key</function-name>
    <function-class>com.mycompany.one.webcore.util.ViewUtils</function-class>
    <function-signature>java.lang.String getEnumMessageKey(java.lang.Enum)</function-signature>
</function>
```

.xhtml component

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" xmlns:cx="http://mycompany.com/taglib">

(...)

    <li>#{i18n[cx:enum_key(cc.attrs.enumParam)]}: #{cc.attrs.afiliado.numeroDocumento}</li>

(...)

</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

And this is a .xhtml located in my .war

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:cnx="http://mycompany.com/taglib"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>

    <composite:attribute name="valuePath"/>
    <composite:attribute name="view"/>

</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>


    <h:selectOneMenu id="tipoDoc" value="#{cc.attrs.valuePath}" converter="com.mycompany.one.webcore.converter.GeneralConverter" styleClass="form-control input-sm" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione.." itemValue="#{null}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{comboView.documentTypes}" var="_ti" itemLabel="#{i18n[cnx:enum_key(_ti)]}" itemValue="#{_ti}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

And finally, this is the error that I get when I try to access a view that includes one of those jar components (that calls the function).

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Function 'cx:enum_key' not found
```

Please ask me any questions if something is not clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mojarra had previously bugs in resolving EL functions in composites. Which Mojarra 2.2.x version exactly are you using? Does it work when you move `xmlns:cx="..."` from root tag into the `<cc:implementation>` tag? Have you also tested it outside the composite, in a normal Facelet?

Comment: I can actually execute the function from composites in my .war
The problem is in the composites that are inside the .jar where the function is :S

Comment: -Version is 2.2.2

-hadn't tried that, but now I did and still doesn't work :(

-Yes, I have tried outside the composite. I call it from many places inside the .war (not all of them are composites).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. 
The problem didn't have anything to do with external jars or whatsoever.

In my code I was calling the function in my .xhtml like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" xmlns:cx="http://mycompany.com/taglib">

(...)

    <li>#{i18n[cx:enum_key(cc.attrs.enumParam)]}: #{cc.attrs.afiliado.numeroDocumento}</li>

(...)

</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

And the EL expression should have been inside a value attribute like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" xmlns:cx="http://mycompany.com/taglib">

(...)

    <li><h:outputText value="#{i18n[cx:enum_key(cc.attrs.enumParam)]} #{cc.attrs.afiliado.numeroDocumento}" /></li>

(...)

</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

So, thanks anyway!

Comment: You've a red herring in your question/answer. Is it `cx:` or `cnx:`?

Comment: Thanks for warningit! Already edited, it was cx: in both cases